# How can I add rewrite rule for custom page?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I'm showing child categories data in custom page using wordpress. Problem is that i'm fetching those child categories from parent category slug.

```
www.example.com/digital-post-page/?cp=category-slug
```

I want to remove `?cp=` and make it like this

```
www.example.com/digital-post-page/category-slug
```

I'm trying following function.

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
   add_rewrite_rule(
    '^digital-post-page/([^/]+)$',
    'index.php?pagename=digital-post-page&show=$matches[1]',
    'top');

}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

But it does not working, can any one guide me regarding this i will appreciate.

Comment: using javascript its possible

Comment: Check that line `'index.php?pagename=digital-post-page&show=$matches[1]'`. I think `show` will be `cp`